Find $a_n$ to make $S_n/a_n\Longrightarrow \mathcal N(0,1)$ given $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\phi(t)}{t^2 \ln |t|}=-1$.
Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be independent identically distributed random variables with density $f(x)= |x|^{-3}$ if $ |x|>1$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, let the characteristic function be $\phi(t):=\mathbb{E} e^{i t X_1}$, let $S_n:=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
It is known that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\phi(t)}{t^2 \ln |t|}=-1$; you do not need to prove this. Using this fact, find a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and prove that $S_n / a_n$ converges in distribution to the standard normal distribution (i.e., mean 0 and variance 1 ).
This problem can be directly solved with Linderberd-Feller theorem, but it's rather complex and I wanted to use the hint it given. However there's a $\ln |t|$ term in $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\phi(t)}{t^2 \ln |t|}=-1$, which will make it hard to directly use Taylor expansions. So my problem is, is there any way to use  the given property $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\phi(t)}{t^2 \ln |t|}=-1$ to solve this problem? Thanks!

How can you apply Linderberg's condition, while the distribution has no finite variance.

@Amir You can truncate the random variables at the level $c_n$ whose value is to be decided later: Define for $1\le m \le n$, $X_{n,m}=X_m 1_{|X_m|\le c_n}$.
For example you can see Example 3.4.13 in Durrett's Probability Theory and Examples 5th edition, where we define $Y_{n, m}=X_m 1_{\left(\left|X_m\right| \leq n^{1 / 2} \log \log n\right)}$ there.

Can you compute the characteristic function of $\frac{S_n}{a_n}$ and chose $a_n$ so that the limit is the characteristic function of $N(0, 1)$?

@Kakashi This is what I wanted to do, I wanted them be the same near $t=0$, but I don’t know how to deal with that $\log(t)$ well…

mimic the proof of theorem 114 on page 65 of https://sas.uwaterloo.ca/~dlmcleis/s901/chapt6.pdf I got $a_n = n^{1/2}\log(n)^{1/2}$. Use simulation to check if this works.

@Kakashi $a_n=n^{1/2}\log(n)^{1/2}$ indeed works. How did you work out this $a_n$? Did you guess it out first or something?

Brute force. You want $\lim_n E(\frac{s}{a_n}(X_1 + \dots + X_n)) = \lim_n \phi(\frac{s}{a_n})^n = \exp(-s^2/2)$. Plug in the asymptotic for $\phi$, and use $(1 + c_n/n + o(c_n))^n \to e^{\lim_n c_n}$ to find what $a_n$ has to satisfy.

A necessary and sufficient condition for the convergence in distribution is pointwise convergence of the characteristic functions. Using this condition, we can determine what $a_n$ has to be for the convergence to happen:
We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{1 - \varphi (t)}{t^2 \ln (| t |)} & = & - 1 + o (1),\\
  1 - \varphi (t) & = & - t^2 \ln (| t |) + o (t^2 \ln (| t |))\\
  \varphi (t) & = & 1 + t^2 \ln (| t |) + o (t^2 \ln (| t |)) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Fix $s \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
  E \left( \frac{s}{a_n}  (X_1 + \cdots + X_n) \right) & = & \varphi \left(
  \frac{s}{a_n} \right)^n\\
  & = & \left( 1 + \frac{s^2}{a_n^2} \ln \left( \frac{| s |}{a_n} \right) + o
  \left( \frac{\ln (a_n)}{a_n^2} \right) \right)^n\\
  & = & \left( 1 + \frac{s^2}{a_n^2} \ln (| s |) - \frac{s^2}{a_n^2} \ln
  (a_n) + o \left( \frac{\ln (a_n)}{a_n^2} \right) \right)^n\\
  & = & \left( 1 - \frac{s^2}{a_n^2} \ln (a_n) + o \left( \frac{\ln
  (a_n)}{a_n^2} \right) \right)^n\\
  & \rightarrow & \exp \left( - \lim_n  \frac{n \ln (a_n)}{a_n^2} s^2 \right)
  .
\end{eqnarray*}
Want
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{n \ln (a_n)}{a_n^2} & = & \frac{1}{2} + o (1),\\
  \frac{2 n \ln (a_n)}{a_n^2} & = & 1 + o (1) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $a_n = n^{1 / 2} b_n$, $b_n = o (n^{1 / 2})$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{n \log (n)}{nb_n^2} & = & 1 + o (1),\\
  b_n^2 & = & \log (n) + o (\log (n)) .
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
  a_n & = & n^{1 / 2} \log (n)^{1 / 2} .
\end{eqnarray*}
